# What is the largest integer number value in scheme/racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to find out how what exactly the largest int value in scheme is?
Like for example, in java, the largest signed int is 2^31 - 1.

How can I get this value in scheme (for the largest int value)

Comment: it's it nice to be freed from having to think about these things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Scheme and Lisp implementations, including Racket, have bignums, which means that integers have practically unlimited magnitude, limited only by available memory.

Asking for the largest int value is like asking for the maximum list length.

Comment: R5RS and earlier did not require a full numeric tower and the report stated that a Scheme which only supported floats can be useful. Thus Racket does not have  bignum out of requirement.

Comment: I never said it was a requirement, just that most implementations have it.

Comment: Maybe you interpreted "support" as meaning they were doing it to support a requirement. I've changed it to "have".

Answer (score 5):

In Racket  the built-in exact numbers are of arbitrary precision